# Quicksort in Lisp Strange behavior?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicksort

I managed to get my quicksort function to work but I'm confused why a slight change of the code causes the function to behave strangely. 
This is the working code:

```
(defun low (mylist)
  (setq result (list))
  (loop
      for x in mylist
      do (if (< x (car mylist))
             (setq result (cons x result))))
  result)

(defun high (mylist)
  (setq result (list))
  (loop
      for x in mylist
      do (if (> x (car mylist))
             (setq result (cons x result))))
  result)

(defun qsort (mylist)
  (if (null mylist)
       nil
       (progn 
         ;(setq l1 (low mylist))
         ;(setq l2 (high mylist))
         (append (qsort (low mylist))
                 (list (car mylist))
                 (qsort (high mylist))))))
```

However in the `qsort` function, if I try to store the partitions in `l1` and `l2` and then call `qsort` the function no longer works:

```
(defun qsort (mylist)
  (if (null mylist)
      nil
      (progn 
        (setq l1 (low mylist))
        (setq l2 (high mylist))
        (append (qsort l1)
                (list (car mylist))
                (qsort l2)))))
```

With this `(qsort (list -3 5 4 3 1 2))` returns `(-3 1 2)`

I know that storing the partitions beforehand is not necessary, but is there a reason why this is not supposed to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are using incorrectly variables in Common Lisp – and this is signalled in most implementations:

```
CL-USER> (defun low (mylist)
           (setq result (list))
           (loop for x in mylist do 
              (if (< x (car mylist)) 
                (setq result (cons x result))))
           result)
;Compiler warnings :
;   In LOW: Undeclared free variable RESULT
LOW
```

Note that the compiler gives you a warning, and not an error, for two reasons:

1. You could introduce later on a global variable named `result`, and then the function execution would be correct;
2. The semantics of `(setq x y)` is such that, if no variable `x` is defined, then the value `y` is assigned to the *symbol* x, which is, in some sense, a kind of global variable.

And it is for this second reason that your function does not work correctly, since in your recursive definition you are using `l1` and `l2` as if they were local variables, instantiated with a different value at each recursive call, while instead they are globally assigned between the different calls, producing an incorrect result.

For a more thorough dicussion on the subject, see for instance the [chapter on variables](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html) of the excellent book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

**The solution**

You should introduce local variables with the `let` special form before using them. For instance, you could write the function `low` in this way:

```
(defun low (mylist)
   (let ((result (list)))
     (loop for x in mylist  
        if (< x (car mylist)) 
        do (setq result (cons x result)))
     result))
```

The `let` introduces the new variable, that you can later assign with the `setq` operator. Here, for instance, is a correct version of `qsort`:

```
(defun qsort (mylist)
    (if (null mylist) 
        nil
        (let ((l1 (low mylist))
              (l2 (high mylist)))
          (append (qsort l1) (list (car mylist)) (qsort l2)))))
```

Finally, note that you could write more concisely and more idiomatically the function `low` in this way (and similarly for `high`):

```
(defun low (mylist)
  (loop for x in mylist
     when (< x (car mylist))
     collect x))
```

**Final note**

Your algorithm (and my rewriting) does not sort correctly a list, since it eliminates duplicate elements (try for instance to apply it to the list `(7 3 2 2 4 9 1)`).

A way of correcting it is to modify one of the two auxiliary functions so to get all the elements which are, for instance, less then or equal to the car of the sublist. Here is the rewriting of the `low` function that produces a correct algorithm:

```
(defun low (mylist)
  (loop for x in (cdr mylist)
     when (<= x (car mylist))
     collect x))
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was answered by Renzo, `l1` and `l2` are global variables. If you trace their values through your definition of `qsort` you get the following trace for the call `(qsort '(-1 4 2 3 0 1))`:

```
L1 = NIL L2 = (1 0 3 2 4)
L1 = (0) L2 = (4 2 3)
L1 = NIL L2 = NIL
(-1 0 1)
```

Meanwhile if you use `let` form, the trace shows:

```
L1 = NIL L2 = (1 0 3 2 4)
L1 = (0) L2 = (4 2 3)
L1 = NIL L2 = NIL
L1 = (3 2) L2 = NIL
L1 = (2) L2 = NIL
L1 = NIL L2 = NIL
```

So, `l1` and `l2` get assigned `NIL` deeper in the recursive call, whereas at the top of it their values were expected to contain non-empty lists.

In general, it is a bad idea to mix up a recursion (read functional programming) and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Renso has the answer but since you already use `loop` you should tap it's potential. Thus you could do this

```lisp
(defun partition (number-list pivot)
  (loop :for number :in number-list
        :if (<= number pivot)
            :collect number :into small
        :else
            :collect number :into large
        :finally (return (values small large))))
```

`qsort` could be done like this to make use of it:

```lisp
(defun qsort (number-list)
  (if (not (cdr number-list))
      number-list
      (multiple-value-bind (small large)
                           (partition (cdr number-list) 
                                      (car number-list))
        (nconc (qsort small) 
               (list (car number-list))
               (qsort large)))))
```